# Java streams not filtering multiple condition , groupby month value of date and calculating sum value in Java 8 features

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I have a problem about writing a java stream by filtering multiple condition, grouping by month of the date and calculating the sum of person.

I store the values as `Map<String(pId),List<Person>>`

Here is my Person class shown below

```
public class Person{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Statement event; // JOIN , EXIT
    private Object value;
    private LocalDate eventDate;
}
```

Here is the list

```
ID,Info,Date (All values are stored in Person object defined in the List)

per1, JOIN,  10-01-2022
per2, JOIN, 10-01-2022
per3, EXIT, 10-01-2022 
per3 EXIT, 10-02-2022
per4, JOIN, 10-03-2022
```

What I want to do is to get this result.

```
Month  Info Total Number
1        JOIN       2
1        EXIT       1
2        EXIT       1
3        JOIN       1
```

Here is my dto shown below.

```
public class DTO {
    private int month;
    private State info;  // State -> enum
    private int totalEmployees;  
}
```

Here is my GroupDto shown below.

```
public class GroupDto {

    private int month;
    private State info;
}
```

Here is the code snippet but I cannot complete it.

```
List<DTO > result = persons .values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .filter(person -> person .getInfo() == Value.ONBOARD || person .getInfo() == Value.EXIT)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    p -> new GroupDto(p.getEventDate().getMonthValue(), p.getEvent()),
                    Collectors.counting()
            ))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new DTO(p.getKey().get, p.getKey(), (int) (long) e.getValue())) // -> ERROR Line
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MonthWiseDto::getMonth))
            .toList();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Sorry, I try to group by month not statement. I also have to filter JOIN and INFO as there are other statements as well.

Comment: You have 1st group by on `Month` and `Event`

Comment: @Deadpool You mentioned about this `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getEventDate().getMonthValue(),Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getEvent()));``.Next, what should I do?

Comment: Since your `DTO` contains both `State` and `month` you need to group by both properties. Otherwise if you want to group only by `month` as you've shown, the `DTO` hold a Collection of `State` (person instances mapped to the same month can have different states).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get the total number of people for every combination of Month and State you need to group the data based on these two properties.

For that, you can define an object that would serve as a key in the intermediate Map. It can be implemented as a Java 16 `record` like that (*you can use a* `class` with earlier JDK version) :

```
public record MonthState(int mont, State info) {}
```

In the stream, we can make use of the Collector `groupingBy()` with Collector [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) passed as a downstream to generate the total number of `Person` objects having particular combination of month and state.

```
Map<String, List<Person>> personListById = // initializing the map

List<DTO> result = personListById.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(per -> per.getInfo() == State.EXIT || per.getInfo() == State.JOIN)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        p -> new MonthState(p.getEventDate().getMonthValue(), p.getInfo()),
        Collectors.counting()
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new DTO(e.getKey().mont(), e.getKey().info(), (int) (long) e.getValue()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(DTO::getMonth))
    .toList();
```

[*Link to online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zGl)

Comment: @S.N So can you clarify is the logic is correct? Because you were insisting that you want to group the data only by month.

Comment: I have one more question to ask you about the value part.  Does Collectors.counting() get the total value of count?

Comment: @S.N Collector [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) would generate the total number of stream elements that is has consumed as `long`. I.e. in this case `grouping()` + `counting()` would create an intermediate map of `Map<MonthState,Long>`, where the Value would be the total number of `Person` objects having a particular combination of month and state.

Comment: @S.N By saying Java 8 you imply that you're using JDK 8 (released 10 ago) or you only refer to the functional features added with Java 8? I've created a [*Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zGl) it would run with Java 16 +.

Comment: I just mentioned Java 8 functional features in the post.

Comment: I have an issue for counting and calculating sum. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74511911/java-streams-not-filtering-multiple-condition-groupby-condition-and-calcuating

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Person> persons = List.of(
                new Person("per1", Statement.JOIN, LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 10)),
                new Person("per2", Statement.JOIN, LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 10)),
                new Person("per3", Statement.EXIT, LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 10)),
                new Person("per3", Statement.EXIT, LocalDate.of(2022, 2, 10)),
                new Person("per4", Statement.JOIN, LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 10)));

        List<Dto> groupResults = calculateGroupResults(persons);
        groupResults.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<Dto> calculateGroupResults(List<Person> persons) {
        Map<GroupKey, Long> map = persons.stream()
                                         .filter(person -> person.getEvent() == Statement.EXIT || person.getEvent() == Statement.JOIN)
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                 person -> new GroupKey(person.getEventDate().getMonthValue(), person.getEvent()),
                                                 Collectors.counting()));

        return map.entrySet().stream()
                  .map(entry -> new Dto(entry.getKey().getMonth(), entry.getKey().getInfo(), entry.getValue()))
                  .sorted(Dto.SORT_BY_MONTH_INFO)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    enum Statement {
        JOIN,
        EXIT
    }

    @Getter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static final class Person {

        private final String id;
        private final Statement event;
        private final LocalDate eventDate;

    }

    @Getter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static final class GroupKey {

        private final int month;
        private final Statement info;

    }

    @Getter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static final class Dto {

        public static final Comparator<Dto> SORT_BY_MONTH_INFO =
                Comparator.comparing(Dto::getMonth)
                          .thenComparingInt(one -> one.getInfo().ordinal());

        private final int month;
        private final Statement info;
        private final long totalEmployees;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return month + "-" + info + '-' + totalEmployees;
        }
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
1-JOIN-2
1-EXIT-1
2-EXIT-1
3-JOIN-1
```

Comment: I tried to use your approach but I couldn't solve my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512927/java-stream-issue-of-calculating-count-sum-of-one-value-and-multiple-group-by-c