# Java Stream Issue of calculating count, sum of one value and multiple group by conditions

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem about writing a java stream by filtering multiple conditions , groupby multiple condition (if possible) and calculating the sum value

I store the values as `Map<String(pId),List<Person>>`

Here is my Person class shown below

```
public class Person{

    private String id;
    private Statement event; // STATUS1,STATUS2
    private LocalDate eventDate;
    private Object value;
}
```

Here is the list

```
ID,Info,Date,Value (All values are stored in Person object defined in the List)

per1, STATUS1,  10-01-2022, 1
per2, STATUS2, 10-01-2022, 2
per3, STATUS3, 10-01-2022, 3
per1, STATUS4, 10-01-2022, 1  
per1 STATUS1, 10-02-2022, 1
per2, STATUS1, 10-03-2022, 1
per3, STATUS2, 10-03-2022, 2
...
...
```

What I want to do is to get this result.

```
Month |  Total Sum | Person Count
1        7          3
2        1          1
3        3          2
```

Here is group dto shown below

```
public class GroupDto {
        private int month;
        private String id;
}
```

Here is my dto shown below.

```
public class DTO {
    private int month;
    private BigDecimal totalSum; 
    private int totalPersons;  
}
```

Here is the code snippet but I cannot handle with it.

```
List<Dto> group = employees.values().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .filter(emp -> emp.getEvent() == Value.STATUS1 || emp.getEvent() == Value.STATUS2 
                        || emp.getEvent() == Value.STATUS3 || emp.getEvent() == Value.STATUS4)
                .map(emp -> new Dto(emp.getEventDate().getMonthValue(), new BigDecimal(emp.getValue().toString()), 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Dto> result = new ArrayList<>(group.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        dto -> Arrays.asList(dto.getMonth()), Function.identity(), Dto::aggregate))
                .values()).stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Dto::getMonth))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

public static Dto aggregate(Dto initial, Dto next) {
        initial.setTotalSalary(initial.getTotalSalary().add(next.getTotalSalary()));
        initial.setTotalEmployees(initial.getTotalEmployees() + next.getTotalEmployees());
        return initial;
    }

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is the same result

```
Dto{month=1, totalSalary=7, totalPersons=4}
Dto{month=2, totalSalary=1, totalPersons=1}
Dto{month=3, totalSalary=3, totalPersons=2}
```

Normally, total persons in month 1 is 3 but it counts 4 with respect to status.

My Issue : I cannot count the person, It counts by status. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a statistics class that models your results. I'm going to use [Java records introduced in JDK 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) to make the examples concise.

First we introduce your model class for Person and your enum. Note that I've changed the `value` to an int type to make the example simpler.

```java
enum Statement {
    STATUS1, STATUS2, STATUS3
}
record Person(String id,
              Statement event,
              LocalDate eventDate,
              int value) {}
```

We will now create a `PersonGroupMetric` that you will use to capture the metrics that you require, it will take a Person as a constructor to allow for easy mapping and has an `add` method that we will use as a combiner later when we provide the implementation for collecting your stream.

```java
record PersonGroupMetric(int count, int sum) {

    public static final PersonGroupMetric EMPTY = new PersonGroupMetric(0, 0);

    public PersonGroupMetric(Person p) {
        this(1, p.value());
    }

    public PersonGroupMetric add(PersonGroupMetric other) {
        return new PersonGroupMetric(
            this.count + other.count,
            this.sum + other.sum
        );
    }
}
```

Given your initial dataset:

```java
var src = List.of(
    new Person("per1", Statement.STATUS1, LocalDate.of(2022, 01, 10), 1),
    new Person("per2", Statement.STATUS2, LocalDate.of(2022, 01, 10), 2),
    new Person("per3", Statement.STATUS3, LocalDate.of(2022, 01, 10), 3),
    new Person("per1", Statement.STATUS1, LocalDate.of(2022, 02, 10), 1),
    new Person("per2", Statement.STATUS1, LocalDate.of(2022, 03, 10), 1),
    new Person("per3", Statement.STATUS2, LocalDate.of(2022, 03, 10), 2)
);
```

We can now use a [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) collector that uses a reducer built from your metric model class:

```java
Map<Integer, PersonGroupMetric> res = src.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        p -> p.eventDate().getMonthValue(),
        reducing(
            PersonGroupMetric.EMPTY,
            PersonGroupMetric::new,
            PersonGroupMetric::add
        )
    ));
```

This now contains a map that groups by the month with the value containing your metric class.

You can now map this to your domain object `DTO` from the maps `entrySet()`:

```java
var fin = res.entrySet().stream()
    .map(n -> new DTO(
        n.getKey(),
        n.getValue().sum(),
        n.getValue().count()
    ))
    .collect(toList());
```

Imports required:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.reducing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Comment: Looks like homework.  I already flagged it,   See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74511911/1552534

Comment: @BrettRyan Thank you for your response but I have to get a list containing dto not map. By the way, this link is not working.

Comment: I have validated both links to be accurate. It should be trivial to map the `entrySet()` to a `DTO` domain class and then collect this. If this is indeed homework, you could at least solve for that part on your own. It should not matter what domain objects used to get to a given result, but the approach to get there.

Comment: @BrettRyan I edited my post with sharing my code. I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: @BrettRyan I created a id for distinct person and I cannot get the right result. What should I do to store ids as set which it's coming in my mind.

Comment: @BrettRyan You defined value as int in Person but it should be Object as other status statments' values are string.

Comment: @BrettRyan There is a problem in personId and I cannot get the right result of total persons. How can I do that?

Comment: I've provided clear instruction on how to get to the desired outcome you are looking for, implementation details to arrive at the outcome are irrelevant and you should be able to use these tools to arrive at your result. I mentioned I used `int` to make the example simpler, I do not know what you're storing in this, but you're trying to sum it, you know better than I what type conversion you should be using for it.